# URL is different when I start gwt-rpc project in eclipse DevMode and on Tomcat 7 Server, so I have issues with PayPal

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, paypal, server

Running on Eclipse URL is: http://127.0.0.1:8080/MovieUniverse.html

Running on Tomcat 7 URL is: http://127.0.0.1:8080/MovieUniverse/MovieUniverse.html

My problem is that when I use PayPal SDK merchant for Paypal Express Checkout, on Server I give to the method that do setCheckoutExpress a return URL and a cancel URL in this way:

```
/*
        '------------------------------------
        ' The returnURL is the location where buyers return to when a
        ' payment has been succesfully authorized.
        '
        ' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
        '------------------------------------
        */


        String returnURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_confirmed";

        /*
        '------------------------------------
        ' The cancelURL is the location buyers are sent to when they hit the
        ' cancel button during authorization of payment during the PayPal flow
        '
        ' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
        '------------------------------------
        */
        String cancelURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_cancelled";
        /*
        '------------------------------------
        ' When you integrate this code 
        ' set the variables below with 
        ' shipping address details 
        ' entered by the user on the 
        ' Shipping page.
        '------------------------------------
        */
setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setReturnURL("http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_confirmed");


setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setCancelURL("http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_cancelled");
```

When I do Express Checkout I get out from my site, and after paypal payment condirm, the service try to load Return or Cancel URL up to success of payment. So the system try to load Return or Cancel URL, but naturally these URLs don't works on Server, because the path is wrong (it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8080/MovieUniverse/MovieUniverse.html#order_confirmed` because it works). So I need a way to get URL to compose a String like this: URLGet+#order_confirmed in order to obtain the right URL . Or maybe another solution could be from the start, when i call onModuleLoad(), change the Url from inside this method.
Do you have a suggest? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution one: Deploy your app in "/" context root of your Tomcat, instead of "/MovieUniverse/"

Solution two: on your server get the context path of deployed app, manipulate url using it.

Comment: I've deleted contents in [TOMCAT_HOME]/webapps, after I have put it inside my file .war and renamed it as ROOT.war. I've after restarted the server tomcat and it has worked. Thanks a lot! You need to be sure that Tomcat is set for the right port (in this case 8080)